# Spark: Task not serializable Exception in forEach loop in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, lambda, rdd

I'm trying to iterate over JavaPairRDD and perform some calculations with keys and values of JavaPairRDD. Then output result for each JavaPair into **processedData** list.

**What I already tried:**
 make variables, that I use inside of lambda function static.
 make methods, that I call from lambda foreach loop static.
 added implements Serializable

Here is my code:

```html
     List<String> processedData = new ArrayList<>();
      
      JavaPairRDD<WebLabGroupObject, Iterable<WebLabPurchasesDataObject>> groupedByWebLabData.foreach(data ->{
     
     JavaRDD<WebLabPurchasesDataObject> oneGroupOfData = convertIterableToJavaRdd(data._2());
          
     double opsForOneGroup = getOpsForGroup(oneGroupOfData);
     double unitsForOneGroup = getUnitsForGroup(oneGroupOfData);
       
     String combinedOutputForOneGroup =  data._1().getProductGroup() + "," + opsForOneGroup + "," + unitsForOneGroup;
         
     processedData.add(combinedOutputForOneGroup);
   });



 private JavaRDD<WebLabPurchasesDataObject> convertIterableToJavaRdd(Iterable<WebLabPurchasesDataObject> groupedElements)
   {
      List<WebLabPurchasesDataObject> list = new ArrayList<>();     
     groupedElements.forEach(el -> list.add(el));
      return this.context.parallelize(list);
   }
```

Here is exception itself:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:158)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1623)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreach(RDD.scala:797)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.foreach(JavaRDDLike.scala:312)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.foreach(JavaRDDLike.scala:46)
at com.amazon.videoads.emr.spark.WebLabDataAnalyzer.processWebLabData(WebLabDataAnalyzer.java:121)
at com.amazon.videoads.emr.spark.WebLabMetricsApplication.main(WebLabMetricsApplication.java:110)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:569)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:110)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala).Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext . Serialization stack:
- object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext, value: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext@395e9596)
- element of array (index: 0)
- array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 2)
- field (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, name: capturedArgs, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
- object (class com.amazon.videoads.emr.spark.WebLabDataAnalyzer$$Lambda$14/1536342848, com.amazon.videoads.emr.spark.WebLabDataAnalyzer$$Lambda$14/1536342848@5acc8c7c)
- field (class: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreach$1, name: f$14, type: interface org.apache.spark.api.java.function.VoidFunction)
- object (class org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreach$1, <function1>)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:164)
... 16 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: you're trying to use a **JavaSparkContext** inside your **groupedByWebLabData** RDD: you can't do that since JavaSparkContext is not serializable.

---

The stacktrace is quite helpful here:

```
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala).Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext . Serialization stack:
```

this means that

- you're trying to serialize something that can't be serialize
- this something is a **JavaSparkContext**

This is caused by those two lines:

```
JavaPairRDD<WebLabGroupObject, Iterable<WebLabPurchasesDataObject>> groupedByWebLabData.foreach(data ->{
 JavaRDD<WebLabPurchasesDataObject> oneGroupOfData = convertIterableToJavaRdd(data._2());
```

because

```
convertIterableToJavaRdd
```

which is called by each element of your RDD, uses

```
this.context.parallelize(list)
```

i.e. it uses a **JavaSparkContext**: you're trying to use a JavaSparkContext on your executors (where the data making your **groupedByWebLabData** RDD lives). Well you can't do that since a JavaSparkContext is not serializable.

Here what you're doing can probably be done via an **UDF** and you can collect the result (if it's not too big).

Comment: How to loop through the rows then?