# Dataset forEach loop in scala throwing SparkException Task not serializable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

My question is really similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49289566/spark-task-not-serializable-exception-in-foreach-loop-in-java) one, except that I'm using Scala.

For the below code:

```
        roleList = res.select($"results", explode($"results").as("results_flat1"))
                        .select("results_flat1.*")
                        .select(explode($"rows").as("rows"))
                        .select($"rows".getItem(0).as("x"))
                        .withColumn("y", trim(col("x")))
                        .select($"y".as("ROLE_NAME"))
                        .map(row => Role(row.getAs[String](0)))

        if (roleList.count() != 0) {
            println(s"Number of Roles = ${roleList.count()}")

            roleList.foreach{role =>
                var status = ""

                do {
                    val response = getDf()
                    response.show()

                    status = response.select("status").head().getString(0)
                    var error = ""

                    error = response.select($"results", explode($"results").as("results_flat1"))
                                .select("results_flat1.*")
                                .select($"error")
                                .first().get(0).asInstanceOf[String]
                }
                while (status != "completed")
            }
        }
```

I'm getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:403)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:393)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2326)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:925)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreach(RDD.scala:925)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply$mcV$sp(Dataset.scala:2716)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2716)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2716)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$withNewRDDExecutionId$1.apply(Dataset.scala:3349)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewRDDExecutionId(Dataset.scala:3345)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.foreach(Dataset.scala:2715)
    at com.cloud.operations.RoleOperations.createRoles(RoleOperations.scala:30)
    at com.cloud.Main$.main(Main.scala:24)
    at com.cloud.Main.main(Main.scala)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.cloud.operations.RoleOperations
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: com.cloud.operations.RoleOperations, value: com.cloud.operations.RoleOperations@67a3394c)
    - field (class: com.cloud.operations.RoleOperations$$anonfun$createRoles$1, name: $outer, type: class com.cloud.operations.RoleOperations)
    - object (class com.cloud.operations.RoleOperations$$anonfun$createRoles$1, <function1>)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:400)
    ... 21 more
```

`RoleOperations.scala:30` refers to the line where `roleList.foreach` starts.

I'm not quite sure as to why this is happening. From the linked question's answer, I'm not using Spark Context anywhere in my code, though `getDf()` does use `spark.read.json` (from `SparkSession`). Even in that case, the exception does not occur at that line, but rather at the line above it, which is really confusing me. Please help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you cant use spark session in functions that are executed on executors. `SparkSession` can be used only from driver code.

In your case everything in `roleList.foreach` is executed on executors, not on driver.

Additionally the same error might arise when someone uses a variable that is defined in class inside executors code. In this case whole class need to be sent to executor, and if it is not serializable - you get this error.

Comment: Ok so what should I do then so that I can iterate over the `roleList` instead of using `roleList.foreach` and not crashing the code?

Comment: You have 2 options - get everything on driver using `collect` - but that is not recommended because you will have all your data on one node - might get OOM error. Or you can re-design your code so that you don't need to use `SparkSession` on executor, if that is possible.